# Filtrar un cronograma con 2 input type date

Tags: php, html

Tengo un cronograma al que quiero poder filtrar 2 fechas mediante un input (date), y los resultados que me aparezcan sean solo los que esten en el rango escogido, como lo haria?

Este es el formulario

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');

$pg = "select * from cronograma order by fecha asc";
$query = pg_query($pg);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Cronograma </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table tr td{
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> <H2> CRONOGRAMA DE CURSOS Y TALLERES </H2> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <table border="3">
                <tr>
                    <td> N° </td>
                    <td> FECHA </td>
                    <td> CURSO / TALLER </td>
                    <td> ENTE </td>
                    <td> PARTICIPANTES </td>
                    <td> SEDE </td>
                    <td> CONTACTO </td>
                    <td> INSTRUCTOR </td>
                    <td> ANALISTA </td>
                    <td> PLAN B </td>
                </tr>
                <?php while($fila = pg_fetch_assoc($query)){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td> <?php echo $fila['id_cronograma']; ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $fila['fecha']; ?> </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php $query2 = "select * from cursos where id_curso =" . $fila['id_curso'] . ""; 
                            $consulta2 = pg_query($conexion, $query2);
                                while($fila2 = pg_fetch_assoc($consulta2)){
                                    echo $fila2['nombre_curso'];
                                }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <?php $query3 = "select * from ente where id_ente =" . $fila['id_ente'] . ""; 
                            $consulta3 = pg_query($conexion, $query3);
                                while($fila3 = pg_fetch_assoc($consulta3)){
                                    echo $fila3['nombre_ente'];
                                }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $fila['num_participantes']; ?> </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php $query4 = "select * from sede where id_sede =" . $fila['id_sede'] . ""; 
                            $consulta4 = pg_query($conexion, $query4);
                                while($fila4 = pg_fetch_assoc($consulta4)){
                                    echo $fila4['nombre_sede'];
                                }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $fila['contacto']; ?> </td>
                    <td> 
                        <?php $query5 = "select * from instructor where id_instructor =" . $fila['id_instructor'] . ""; 
                            $consulta5 = pg_query($conexion, $query5);
                                while($fila5 = pg_fetch_assoc($consulta5)){
                                    echo $fila5['nombre_instructor'] . " " . $fila5['apellido_instructor'];
                                }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <?php $query6 = "select * from analista where id_analista =" . $fila['id_analista'] . ""; 
                            $consulta6 = pg_query($conexion, $query6);
                                while($fila6 = pg_fetch_assoc($consulta6)){
                                    echo $fila6['nombre_analista'] . " " . $fila6['apellido_analista'];
                                }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <?php $query7 = "select * from analista where id_analista =" . $fila['plan_b'] . "";
                            $consulta7 = pg_query($conexion, $query7);
                                while($fila7 = pg_fetch_assoc($consulta7)){
                                    echo $fila7['nombre_analista'] . " " . $fila7['apellido_analista'];
                            }

                        ?> 
                    </td>

                    <?php $total = $fila['num_participantes'] + $total; ?>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>  
            </table>
        </form>
        <br>
        <input type="date" name="fecha"> <input type="date" name="fecha">
    </center>
</body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Algo asi como la imagen?
tienes que ser mas especifico, puedes utilizar datepicker.
y pasar los datos por `JS` , validarlos y mandarlos a tu sentencia `sql`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si, como en la imagen es lo que necesito, y como haria lo del js, porque en realidad no lo manejo muy bien

Comment: Crea tu formulario en `html` y subelo con eso te ayudo un poco mas

Comment: ya puse mi formulario hermano

Comment: lo vas a manejar con un boton? es decir fecha inicio fecha fin y su boton buscar?

Comment: Preferiria que no